# Rails3 plugin - load environment for rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, rake, ruby-on-rails-3

What should I do to load rails models for rake task which is part of my plugin?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Require the :environment rake task to run before it.

```
task :my_task => :environment do

end
```

Comment: This is literally ':environment', not a defined environment like test, development, or production.