# Ruby on Rails - Can I call a Controller:Method from a batch routine in windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, command-line, scheduled-tasks

I'm relatively new to RoR working on Windows. I built a simple app in Rails that sends email using ActionMailer. I'd like to add a task to my windows scheduler to run a batch routine that calls my email method inside of my controller. The web app will not be running when I do this, so I can't do a CURL or something similar. Is there a way to run Ruby.exe with some args to launch a rails app (similar to irb) and call a controller:method?

**Update: I took the advice in the answer I marked correct, but I thought I'd elaborate in case a RoR newbie like myself needs a bit more guidance.**

1. I created a folder app\classes and I created a .rb file for my class
2. I had to create an initialize method to handle some setup
3. Created a few methods that simple return variables
4. I made sure I could run the steps in **rails console**
5. Created a file in lib\tasks with the code below
6. Ran this in DOS in the project folder - **rake runMe --trace**

   ```
   task :runMe => :environment do

       @s = ScrapeTools.new

       @bears = @s.getBears

       @bulls = @s.getBulls

       UserMailer.stock_email(@bears,@bulls).deliver

   end
   ```

*Please let me know if you see any errors*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a good example of why you don't want to put logic in your controller. Much better than putting that functionality in a controller method, refactor it to a method in a module or class. Then you call that method from your controller as well as from a rake task that is straight-forward to execute in your batch routine.

Comment: If I put it in a module, how would I call if from a rake task?

Comment: Have the rake task require the environment (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482967/rails3-plugin-load-environment-for-rake-task). Then you can call any method available in your app the same you would from your controller. For example `MyModule.my_method(args)` if you defined my_method as "class method" of MyModule

Comment: Interesting that it's been downvoted when it's a correct (and the accepted) answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is. `rails runner <path to script>` will run the given script under your Rails app. [Have some docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner)

Comment: So my controller is defined here class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

My method is defined here "def stocks"

I'm trying this in DOS  rails runner -e development 'WelcomeController.stocks'

with this error runner.rb:53:in `eval': undefined method `stocks' for WelcomeController:Class (NoMethodError)

Any ideas??

Comment: @user1108728. The problem is that stock is an instance method of WelcomeController, not a class method. You would need an instance of the controller, which you don't want to do. Please see my response above to avoid all this.

Comment: Your response above says to use rails runner, which is what I thought I did? I do not know the difference between an instance method and a class method, is there a better day to def stocks?

Comment: @user1108728. Sorry about the confusion. My response is the one by boulder (me), recommending refactoring your code to a module. And fyi, A class method is the equivalent of a static method in other languages, a method of the WelcomeController class, while an instance method is a method of an instance of WelcomeController. Again, avoid all this by moving your code out of the controller.